# User control's custom callback(vb)

Tags: javascript, vb.net, user-controls

I built a gridview in ascx page of a user control with custom button inside the command column and I tried to manage the `CustomButtonClick` in the `ClideSideEvents`, like this:

```
(ASCX)
    <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton        ID="ASPxCustomCommandButton1"/>
     <ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="OnCustomButtonClick" /> 
(JAVASCRIPT)
    function OnCustomButtonClick(s, e) {
                if (e.buttonID == 'ASPxCustomCommandButton1') {
                    e.processOnServer = false;
                    PopupControlUpload.Show();
                     PopupControlUpload.PerformCallback(e.visibleIndex); 
(VB)
    Private Sub ASPxGridView1_CustomButtonCallback(sender As Object, e As ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventArgs) Handles ASPxGridView1.CustomButtonCallback
        Select Case e.ButtonID
            Case "ASPxCustomCommandButton1"
                  //do something"
        End Select
```

i can't get the id of button in javascript and i can't go in vb callback as conseguence. how can i do that in a user control? seems that "e" is not defined so he can't get buttonID from it. In the normal web page it work, but in the user control give me that issue.

Comment: I take it the issue is that `if (e.buttonID == 'ASPxCustomCommandButton1') {` ... what is `buttonID` property? why is it `ButtonID` in VB? where is it declared at all?

Comment: buttonID is a property of the element "e" that contain the button

Comment: and, what is the output of `console.log('buttonID is', e.buttonID)` if you put that as the first line of `function OnCustomButtonClick(s, e) {`

Comment: nothing, because i don't know why in a user control, the code e.buttonID result in a "e" undefined, then i can't get the ID of button. In a normal aspx page that work perfectly

Comment: so, e is undefined? how do you know, is there an error saying `can't get buttonID of undefined` when you try what I suggested?

Comment: i've seen it before in debug, "e is not defined" so it can't take the buttonID

Comment: perhaps you should mention in the question that `e` is `undefined` - if that's the case

Comment: i'll add that in the question right now, thank you

Comment: Can you provide list of messages inside browser console? I tried using custom command column button in ASCX page with `ASPxGridView` & still works. Possibly other errors affect definitions so that `ASPxGridView` custom button event args not counted as defined.